# What does newermt mean in find command?

Tags: command-line, find

I know I can use this option to find file between particular modified times. But I'm curious about what does this mean?

I used `man find | grep newermt` trying to find something. But I got no direct content. It seems `-newer file` and `mtime` stuff may have relation with it. But I'm not sure..

So, what does `-newermt` actually mean?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`find(1)`:

```
-newerXY reference
          Compares the timestamp of the current file with reference.   The
          reference  argument  is  normally the name of a file (and one of
          its timestamps is used for the comparison) but it may also be  a
          string  describing  an  absolute time.  X and Y are placeholders
          for other letters, and these letters select which time belonging
          to how reference is used for the comparison.

          a   The access time of the file reference
          B   The birth time of the file reference
          c   The inode status change time of reference
          m   The modification time of the file reference
          t   reference is interpreted directly as a time
```

Comment: The man for find I found online didn't have this. https://linux.die.net/man/1/find Thanks

Comment: I think that's not being updated regularly. Give this one a try: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

Answer (score 30):

`find ./ -mtime +n` used to get all files older than `n` days
`find ./ -mtime -n` used to get all files modified in last `n` days
Now if you are using `1` in place of `n`, you will get files modified in the last 24 hours. But what if you want only files from yesterday and not within the last 24 hours? Here `newermt` comes into the picture.

```
find ./ -newermt "2016-01-18" ! -newermt '2016-01-19'
```

will give you all files which are newer than specified date and `!` will exclude all files which are newer than the specified date. So the above command will give a list of files which were modified on 2016-01-18.

Comment: I would say "which are newer than specified date, time 00:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `-newermt`, natural language is tricky. 
You say "newer than", but one should say "newer than or equal to". 
Mathematically, this corresponds to the sign ‘≥’, not to ‘>’.

`-newermt given-date` means *file-date* ≥ *`given-date`.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this appears to be wrong. When I do `touch file1; sleep 60; touch file2; sleep 60; touch file` and then `find . -newer file2` (or, equivalently, `-newermm file2`), I get only `file3`, not `file2`. If the test were *newer **or equal**,* it would report that the modification time of `file2` is equal to itself.

Comment: I did a more accurate test to check this: 1. `touch -t 202209090909 foo`; 2. `ls -l --time-style=full-iso foo` (which shows `2022-09-09 09:09:00.000000000`); 3. `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name foo -newermt '2022-09-09 09:09:00'` yields nothing; but 4. `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name foo -newermt '2022-09-09 09:08:59'` finds the test file.

Comment: Yes, comments above are true - it is not greater than or equal - it is greater than - but for most real purposes it will work as greater than or equal because if you say -newermt '2022-09-09 09:00' it means newer than 2022-09-09 09:00:00.000000000, which means all times after that will be included. What are the chances that your file is created at time with all zeros - probably zero! So I think comment deserves +1, not -1.

Comment: @blur You're right for the typical case, but this doesn't apply where a timestamp is set explicitly and does not use microsecond resolution, e.g. with `touch` or when extracting files from an archive that have been published with a particular date.